# Fastest way to find count of selected items in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, count

I know how to find COUNT,AVG functions works want I'm trying to achieve here is another operation after the count is found please see my code below.

```
Article::where('id','=',130)
            ->select(
                'articles.*',
                DB::raw('(SELECT avg(rating) FROM rating WHERE rateable_id = articles.id AND type = "article"  ) as avgRating'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE commentable_id = articles.id AND commentable_type = "article") as commentCount'),
                DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM article_favourites WHERE article_id = articles.id ) as favouriteCount')
            )
            ->get();
```

Using the above query, I can get 'avgRating', 'commentCount', 'favouriteCount', but I also want to get the sum of these three.. i.e. something like:

`(avgRating + commentCount + favouriteCount) AS Sum`

What is the best way to do this? PS: I already have a solution

```
DB::raw('( (SELECT avg(rating) FROM rating WHERE rateable_id = article.id AND type = "article")+(SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE commentable_id = article.id AND commentable_type = "'.$type.'")+(SELECT count(*) FROM article_favourites WHERE article_id = article.id) ) as totalCount'),
```

But I am looking for a better solution

Comment: IMHO you are overthinking this, just add them up in php. In MySQL you would have to repeat the subqueries and add them up as a 4th expression in your query.

Comment: i need to sort 50000 rows with the total result value .. how about that?

Comment: Then you may want to use fluent.

Comment: @Shadow is right. Summing in php will be faster in comparison to your solution.

Comment: so you are asking me to fetch 50000 rows then sum up the seperate counts and then sort(using totalCount) & paginate the rows using array chunks?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment about 50,000 rows. I think the best thing to be mindful of here is indexes. As long as `commentable_id`, `rateable_id` and `article_id` are indexed (assuming of course `articles.id` is a primary key), you should relatively get a fast query.

In terms of simplification, a most readable code (which will likewise be slower) will be to use relations or joins in conjunction with fluent to find the count. i.e. something like

```
$articles->comments()->count()
```

In addition, if you're dealing with large data that may grow to millions of rows and you need to perform a function like sorting, then you're far better off with a summary table. Or you may add the fields like `commentCount`, `avgRating` and `favoriteCount`. The overhead of running these aggregates and using it to sort your data all the time would simply be too much.